# debugging plunker in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, plunker

I created a javascript file in Plunker and I want to debug it. When I open 'Sources' panel, I don't see js file that I created. I only see plenty of Plunker js files. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have two main options to drill down to the source file that you created.

**1. Use the pop-up window mode of the preview panel**

By default, the previewer runs inside an `<iframe>` inside the plunker webapp. You can ask plunker to show the previewer in a separate window by clicking the blue expand icon in the top right of the preview window. If you open dev tools for the pop-up window, you will only see *your* source files.

**2. Right click the preview and hit *inspect element***

Doing it this way will let you use the embedded, live preview and will give you a shortcut to drill down to the DOM associated with your code.

Answer (score 38):

Another way is to put this in your javascript file

> debugger;

and leave the console open, which will force the debugger to not only stop there but to also open the file.

Answer (score 5):

The picture is worth thousand words...
F12 and then select sources; plunkerPreviewTarget has the source code

[image: plunker debug chrome]

Answer (score 2):

A quicker way I found is to simply grab the unique ***id*** of your plnk.

In normal ***'edit'*** mode URL will be something like

`http://plnkr.co/edit/P0fqZG6G6khKKrtfBkDP?p=preview`

Simply append this ***id*** - **P0fqZG6G6khKKrtfBkDP** to the URL

`http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/` therefore becoming

**http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/P0fqZG6G6khKKrtfBkDP/**

**Important:** Make double sure you add the trailing **/**

- `Open new URL in a new chrome window`
- `Hit F12 in chrome, voila native angular JS debugging for your plnk`

**Note:** You can then continue editing in plnkr, saving, and simply refreshing this URL when debugging, to maintain your active debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

This may change, but currently on Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m on Windows 10, 64 bit, this is how you can find your plunk source files:

- **Open developer tools (F12)**
- **Open sources**
- **Look for run.plnkr.co**
- **Expand this to show a single directory with a cryptic name**

Inside, you will find your files so you can start debugging